# PHP MYSQLi: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to get the id of a table and make it a variable so I can use it in a link.

But I am getting Notice: Array to string conversion in .

```html
$getpID = "SELECT id from posts";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $getpID) or die(mysqli_error()); 
$pid = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

<a id='del' href='deletepost.php?del=$pid'>Delete</a>
```

This is just a part of the code where I have problems.

Comment: `SELECT id from posts` is in all likely hood returning more than one record, and the `mysqli_fetch_assoc` is turning that result into an associatve array, that you need to either iterate over, or target one item in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like this:-

```
<?php
$getpID = "SELECT id from posts";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $getpID) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
while($pid = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
echo "<a id='del' href='deletepost.php?del=$pid['id']'>Delete</a><br/>"; 
}
```

Note:- this is because `$res` is an `result-set array object` having 1 or more than value. So you need to iterate like this.

Answer (score 0):

`$pid` is an array, you need to access the ID from the array then you can use it in the link. 
Example:

```
$id = $pid['id'];

<a id="del" href="deletepost.php?del=$id">Delete</a>
```